# Google shows subdomain of main site instead of add on domain URL

Tags: google, domains, url, subdomain, search-results

I use Lunarpages and have set up a few add on domains to my main account.  These show up as sub-domains of my main account, but they can be reached by using the new domain I've created.

So:

`subdomain1.example.com` --> `www.example1.com`
`subdomain2.example.com` --> `www.example2.com`

The problem is that `example1.com` shows up in Google with that domain but `example2.com` shows up with `subdomain2.example.com`. I'd the Google search results to display the domains without using a sub domain.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with another provider and it is really not their fault. It is still a mystery to me how Google was able to find the subdomain path since I never wrote it anywhere.

The more robust solution is to setup your .htaccess so to give a 301 redirect when the wrong domain is accessed. For completeness I also do it for the non www version of the domain. That way Google always resolves and attributes PageRank to the official name. This is simple to do as long as .htaccess are enabled and setup properly.

Here is what one of mine looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realdomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.realdomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.realdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.realdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in apache when Vhosts are not configured properly, I'd suggest talking to your host as they will probably have to do the work on the server (unless you manage your own servers).

If you can't get it resolved through your host you should be able to create a 301 redirect using an .htaccess file (it's better to fix the server configuration though if you can).